# (Annotation Processing) Why Filer does not (mostly) allow overwriting?

Tags: java, file, annotation-processing

Based on the Javadoc of [Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html)

> The [Filer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html) interface discusses restrictions on how processors can operate on files.

Therefore, I presume other forms of file manipulation, such as with [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) are not a good practice.
My question is why in `Filer` it was decided not to allow overwriting files that are generated with annotation processors? What are the pros and cons? I understand that overwriting the source code or other critical objects may pose security risks, but what about those generated by processors?